# How to edit a binary executable CLI tool with a hex editor and still run it?

Tags: command-line, homebrew, zsh

I'd like to edit a binary executable CLI tool with a hex editor, and still be able to run it afterwards. Currently, when I edit the file and then run it, I get "zsh: killed [cli tool]". The CLI tool is installed via brew, if that adds clarity or important detail.

Comment: Why do you want to edit a binary?

Comment: What exactly do you edit in the binary?

Comment: After creating a github PR, graphite (a proprietary tool) prints out a link to the PR not on github, but on graphite.dev, which is not where I want to go after creating a github PR. It's a rust binary that wraps a javascript app, so editing the JS is fairly easy.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to re-codesign the binary after changing it, as the original signature is invalidated by changing the contents of the executable file.

An alternative is to disable System Integrity Protection completely to avoid the system validating the signature of the program. However, in most use cases that is not a good idea.

Comment: Does Homebrew codesign binaries?

Comment: Depends on various things, but it can yes. On Apple Silicon it is very much the case

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to a pointer from @jksoegaard, this is how I signed it:

```
codesign -s - -f -vvvvvv [executable binary]
```